# Terminal closes abruptly during MoveIt 2 source build

Tags: ros2, moveit, build-from-source, source

I'm encountering an issue while building MoveIt 2 from source following [the official documentation](https://moveit.ros.org/install-moveit2/source/). The problem is that the terminal closes automatically before the build process completes.

##### Steps Taken

1. Cloned MoveIt2 repository from https://moveit.ros.org/install-moveit2/source/.
2. Followed the instructions in the documentation for setting up the workspace.
3. Ran the following command for building MoveIt2:

   ```
   cd $COLCON_WS
   colcon build --event-handlers desktop_notification- status- --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .
   ```

##### Issue Details

After executing the build command, the terminal closes abruptly, and I'm unable to determine the cause. I've checked the system resources, and it seems to have sufficient CPU and memory.

##### Error Messages

Unfortunately, I don't see any error messages because the terminal closes too quickly. Is there a way to capture the error logs or prevent the terminal from closing automatically during the build process?

##### System Information

- OS: Ubuntu 22.04
- ROS Version: Humble

Any guidance or suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Darshi, one way you would be able to provide us with a log is if you use the `tee` tool.  Can you run `colcon build --event-handlers desktop_notification- status- --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release . | tee error.log` and paste the contents of the subsequent log file generated? This will help understand why your installation fails

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Can you please allow the `colcon` to compile as usual by ignoring the event handler. Please use the following command. `colcon build --cmake-args -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` . I believe in this way, `colcon` should show you complete logs. Also, please clean your workspace.

Comment: I am facing an error while running colcon build in my ROS 2 workspace. The specific error is as follows:


**CMake Error in rosidl_adapter: AttributeError: module 'em' has no attribute 'Interpreter'  **